# Bioinformatics basics

Tags: bioinformatics

What are the basic differences between genbank, NCBI and entrez gene?
And please tell some books and webpages where I can get more about the databases .(currently I'm using Bioinformatics and functional Genomics by Pavsner)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a *"please hold my hand and walk me through this paper/concept/idea"* site. I strongly suggest you take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Use Google to find websites, that's what it's there for. Go to the databases themselves, they **all** have help pages.

Comment: are you a university student or perhaps a graduate student? there are resources to help with this sort of thing - but it depends on what your status is - but I completely agree with MattDMo, though - this site is not what you need

Answer (score 2):

Genbank is a database of nucleotide sequences that are public.

NCBI stands for "National Center for Biotechnology Information" (in the US).

Entrez is NCBI's retrieval system.

You can find more information in [this article](https://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1781245/)

I don't know which kind of databases you are looking for, but there are hundreds of them!
In this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_database) there are some of them.

Comment: This is probably what the OP was after. This answer answers the question correctly and succinctly so I'm not sure why it received a downvote other than you were setup to fail because of the off-topic question.